# Multiple Icons Activity Alias Android

Tags: android

I have an android app where I want the app icon to be changed. I know this can be done through making a

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="jordanzimmittidevelopers.com.communityservicelogger" >

    // Allows Write To External Storage For Backup, Restore, And Print Features//
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    // Allows Phone To Vibrate//
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    // Basic Application Information//
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/RedTheme" >

        // List Activity Information//
        <activity
            android:name=".ListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity-alias
            android:targetActivity=".ListActivity"
            android:name=".OrangeTheme"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_o"
            android:enabled="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>

        // Theme Activity Information//
        <activity
            android:name=".ThemeChooser"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_theme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        // New Event Activity Information//
        <activity
            android:name=".NewEvent"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_new_event"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        // Change Activity Information//
        <activity
            android:name=".Change"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_change"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        // Settings Activity Information//
        <activity
            android:name=".Settings"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        // TutorialPage1 Activity Information//
        <activity
            android:name=".TutorialPage1"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tutorial_page1"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>

        // TutorialPage2 Activity Information//
        <activity
            android:name=".TutorialPage2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tutorial_page2"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>

        // TutorialPage3 Activity Information//
        <activity
            android:name=".TutorialPage3"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tutorial_page3"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>

        // Print Activity Information//
        <activity
            android:name=".PrintEvents"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_print_database" >
        </activity>

        // About Activity Information//
        <activity
            android:name=".About"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about" >
        </activity>

     </application>

</manifest>
```

By default its disabled. I want the user to enable it on button click so I have this code for my onClick for my button :

```
getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
                new ComponentName(this, ".ListActivity"),
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,    
PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

But when I click on the button the app force closes and I get The error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component class .OrangeTheme does
>   not exist in jordanzimmittidevelopers.com.communityservicelogger

Even though as seen above its in my manifest. Any idea what the issue is

Thanks You!